# an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Tags: spring

Error creating bean with name 'Xmlmessageservice' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'messageService' of bean class [com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml.Xml

I am neewbie to spring and i have spend more than a hour to find whats the error can anyone help me with this error?Thanks in advance :)

Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


  <context:component-scan base-package="com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml"></context:component-scan>


 
  <bean id="twitterservice" class="com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml.TwitterxmlService">
  
  </bean> 
  <bean id="Xmlmessageservice" class="com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml.Xmlmessageservice">
        <property name="messageService" ref="twitterservice"></property>
  </bean>
  

</beans>
```

TwitterXmlService.java

```
package com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.swami.demo.constructorbased.MessageService;

public class TwitterxmlService{
    private Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwitterxmlService.class);
    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        logger.info("TwitterService->{}",msg);
    }
    
}
```

XmlMessageService.java

```
package com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml;

public class Xmlmessageservice {
    //private Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(Xmlmessageservice.class);
    public TwitterxmlService messageService;
    public Xmlmessageservice(TwitterxmlService messageService) {
        this.messageService=messageService;
    }
    
    public TwitterxmlService getMessageService() {
        return messageService;
    }

    public void message(String msg) {
        messageService.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

DriverClass

```
package com.swami.demo.springin5steps;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.swami.demo.springin5steps.xml.Xmlmessageservice;

public class SpringIn5StepsXMLApplication {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Xmlmessageservice xmessage=applicationContext.getBean(Xmlmessageservice.class);
        xmessage.message("hi");
        applicationContext.close();
        
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to assign **twitterservice** reference to field **messageService** in **Xmlmessageservice** constructor during bean creation, it did not find the setter for that field. For Assigning, its needs a setter method for the field **messageService**

Missing Code in Xmlmessageservice class:

```
public void setMessageService(TwitterxmlService messageService) {
    this.messageService = messageService;
}
```

**Note**: Please also use better naming strategies for bean ids, field names & class names.

Bean id, field names - camel cased (example: xmlMessageService - bean id)

Class Names - Pascal Cases (example: XmlMessageService - class name)

Comment: I added the setter, and still didn't work. But latter I added the getter to and it worked!